# Apache/Linux CentOS (32bit) Not Loading PHP Modules

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos5, php5

This is probably an easy question, but I've been at it for days with no luck. I need soap enabled to run an application on linux CentOS/Apache. I have PHP installed and have loaded soap.so in /usr/lib/php/modules/. I also have edited php.ini to point to the correct extensions directory. After restarting apache though, the recognized modules simply do not change in phpinfo();. I am baffled. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you install soap extension? What is the output of `php -i | grep soap`?

Comment: I unpacked a php tarball with soap enabled in /home/ and copied the module into the php modules directory. Running that command gives me: Failed loading /usr/lib/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: I only did so because yum install gave some sort of versioning error.

Comment: Can Apache read that file?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to edit your php.ini to remove ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so. Then try reloading php. SOAP generally comes with PHP 5 as a standard installed module. Unless the user has specifically recompiled PHP to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Thomas, you should use the default SOAP library enabled with PHP 5. However, you may have overwritten it when trying to install the initial SOAP lib. Also, take a look at php.ini for the section labeled [soap].

Then make sure you have this file in /etc/php.d/:

$more soap.ini

;Enable soap extension module

extension=soap.so